# node base64 encode pdf with signatures

Tags: node.js, pdf, digital-signature

I'm having problem to encode PDF with signatures to base64. I have this code, which is working, but there is no signatures present:

```
// function to encode file data to base64 encoded string
function base64_encode(file) {
  // read binary data
  var bitmap = fs.readFileSync(file);
  // convert binary data to base64 encoded string
  return new Buffer(bitmap).toString("base64");
}
```

I get base64 encoded data, but it does not have signatures in it?

Answer (score 1):

Rendering an entire PDF file to Base64 encoding would do nothing to remove a signature from within a PDF. Once the signature is there, a base64 encoding and decoding should give you the exact same data as you started with. So if you are decoding a PDF file that does not have any signatures, you must not have encoded a PDF file that contains PDF signatures.

Actually signing a PDF is a multi-step process of saving a PDF, calculating hash values for large sections of the file, and then writing in those hash values into an area of the file that was not part of the hash input.

So I believe that you may be encoding a version of the file that has not been fully updated/saved since the signature was "added".